# Select Radio buttons from multiple form

Tags: angularjs

Am having multiple form on same page . That form contains product name and their prices for monthly ,quarterly.  i used radio btn to select prices for either monthly or quarterly. But if user wants to subscribe for multiple product , how he/she can select radio btn for that product.Any solution?[image]

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want the user to be able to select more than one product at the same time?

Comment: yes user  is allowed to select multiple products at a time

Answer (score 1):

HTML radio buttons are working with their names. So in case you want separate radio buttons for each product, each of your radio buttons has to have different name. So for example:

```
<!-- Product 1 -->
<input type="radio" name="product-1" value="monthly" /> Monthly<br/>
<input type="radio" name="product-1" value="quarterly" /> Quarterly<br/>


<!-- Product 2 -->
<input type="radio" name="product-2" value="monthly" /> Monthly<br/>
<input type="radio" name="product-2" value="quarterly" /> Quarterly<br/>
```

In case you want multiple selection, I suggest you to use checkbox instead of radio buttons.

```
<!-- Product 1 -->
<input type="checkbox" name="product-1" value="monthly" /> Monthly<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="product-1" value="quarterly" /> Quarterly<br/>


<!-- Product 2 -->
<input type="checkbox" name="product-2" value="monthly" /> Monthly<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="product-2" value="quarterly" /> Quarterly<br/>
```

With CSS it's possible to hide checkbox and style it so they look like radio buttons.

Comment: i already given different names  to radio group , but still not working, i also thought of using checkbox , but the issue is user will select both monthly & quarterly . but user only select either monthly or quarterly from each product

Comment: Did you try checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checkbox on products too, this will helps you to select main product with one of option, for example:

> product A and monthly **And** product B and quarterly

to get unique name you can use `{{$index}}` in `ng-repeat` as this sample

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.products = [
       {monthly: 8000, quarterly: 18000},
       {monthly: 9000, quarterly: 28000},
       {monthly: 10000, quarterly: 38000},
       {monthly: 11000, quarterly: 48000},
       {monthly: 12000, quarterly: 58000}
    ];
    
    $scope.get = function() {
      var selectedProducts = $filter('filter')($scope.products, {selected: true});
      console.log(selectedProducts)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h3>multiple selecte with radio mode</h3>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="product.selected">

        <label>
          monthly: {{product.monthly}}
          <input type="radio" name="type_{{$index}}" ng-value="0" ng-model="product.type">
        </label>
        <label>
          quarterly: {{product.quarterly}}
          <input type="radio" name="type_{{$index}}" ng-value="1" ng-model="product.type">
        </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <h3>multiple selecte with checkbox mode</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="product.selected">

        <label>
          monthly: {{product.monthly}}
          <input type="checkbox" name="type_{{$index}}" ng-model="product.monthlySelected">
        </label>
        <label>
          quarterly: {{product.quarterly}}
          <input type="checkbox" name="type_{{$index}}" ng-model="product.quarterlySelected">
        </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  
  <button ng-click="get()">get products</button>

</div>
```

Comment: according to your code when i click on get products it will show selected products . but have u seen radio buttons are showing selected only single product .

Comment: it's an idea, you can m,ix it with top answer i mean use `checbox`  instead `radio` this answer will get you products with on option.

Comment: @PriyankaJain, i update answer with `checbox` too, and i was forget to change name in the source